# When Textfield is clicked, .fullScreenCover dismisses itself

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Having a weird issue where my keyboard is dismissing automatically my `.sheet`. I'll attach a gif below. When I click on any textfield, the sheet will dismiss. In the gif as well I showed the functionality without the keyboard to show the view does not dismiss when not toggled.

No idea where to begin with this. If someone can point me in the right direction that'll be great, as it'll be tough to create a good minimal reproducible example with the code I have. As a note, nowhere in my code am I toggling the view to disappear.

[image]

Calling my sheet below

```
  TabView {
           ForEach(Array(allRecipes.chunked(into: 6)), id: \.self) { recipesChunk in
               LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                  ForEach(recipesChunk, id: \.id) { recipe in
                     
                      self.item(image: recipe.recipeImage, title: recipe.recipeTitle, ingredients: recipe.ingredientItem, directions: recipe.directions, recipeID: recipe.id, recipeCaloriesMacro: recipe.recipeCaloriesMacro, recipeFatMacro: recipe.recipeFatMacro, recipeCarbMacro: recipe.recipeCarbMacro, recipeProteinMacro: recipe.recipeProteinMacro, prepTime: recipe.recipePrepTime)
                         
                      .onTapGesture {
                        selectedRecipe = recipe
                    }
                  }
               }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                   .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedRecipe){
                       RecipeControllerModal(name: $0.recipeTitle, prepTime: $0.recipePrepTime, image: $0.recipeImage, ingredients: $0.ingredientItem, directions: $0.directions, recipeID: $0.id, recipeCaloriesMacro: $0.recipeCaloriesMacro, recipeFatMacro: $0.recipeFatMacro, recipeCarbMacro: $0.recipeCarbMacro, recipeProteinMacro: $0.recipeProteinMacro)
              
               }
           }
       }
```

Textfield

```
TextField("ex. I am a textfield", text: $userDirection)
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding(.leading, 45)
                    .padding(.top, 15)
```

Comment: move the `.fullScreenCover(...)` outside the `ForEach`.

Comment: I tried moving it outside TabView and still closes unfortunately